# Update sql database from FoxPro data on Glassfish server

Tags: java, glassfish, javafx

I'm building a system which includes JavaFX clients pulling data from a MS SQL server via servlets on a glassfish app server.  I also consume some data from a Visual FoxPro database that comes from a legacy system which can't be modified.  I'm using the JDataConnect library to create a JDBC connection on the glassfish server against which I can make regular SQL queries to get the data I need.

My javafx clients include many tableviews which are bound to ObservableLists of data retrieved from the databases.  There is one table which is a composite of data from the MS SQL data and the FoxPro data.  The FoxPro data is updated from a different system.  Since there are many ways for the client to slice and dice the data they present to the user, it is prohibitive to try to keep this composite data in sync (not impossible, but difficult).  It would be easier (and better for the design of the clients) to update columns in relevant tables in the MS SQL db with the necessary values from the FoxPro database as they change.  And since many clients will be accessing the data, it's not wise to have the clients trying to update the database.

So, can I write an application which will run on the glassfish server that will monitor the foxpro database and write the necessary changes/data to the the SQL server database?  I just don't know where to start to develop this type of solution, if indeed, this is what the experts would suggest.  I'm not even sure what to search for.  Totally lost sums it up best.

Thanks for any help or ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You may not be able to modify the legacy FoxPro system, but if the tables are stored in a VFP Database container (i.e. DBC file), you may be able to write stored procedure triggers (insert, update and/or delete) within the VFP database container and have them write directly to the SQL server db.
You'd need:

1. Access to the VFP database container
2. Connection string to the SQL server database
3. To write VFP stored procedure triggers for the VFP data you want pushed up to the SQL Server tables.

Once you have the connection sorted out, you can write VFP stored procedures using SQLEXEC() command which sends a "SQL statement to the data source, where the statement is processed" (from VFP help). E.g.

```
m.lnFileHandle = SQLSTRINGCONNECT(m.lcConnectString)
m.lcSQLCommand = "insert into elctablebk.dbo.t_bkcust (custidnum) values ('EdTest')"
m.lnRetVal = SQLEXEC(m.lnFileHandle, m.lcSQLCommand)
```

The above code gets a filehandle # from connecting to the server, a variable is created with an SQL INSERT command, and the SQL statement is executed on the server using the SQLEXEC() command. If successful, a record is inserted in the example t_bkcust file on the server.

Comment: I don't know much about the VFP side; is there anything that needs to be installed or configured to allow the push to SQL Server other than a connection string?

Comment: I do most of my connections to sql server from vfp using ODBC. When you MODIFY DATABASE in VFP, a Connections section is available from the menu. You can set up your connecton to your sql server db from there. Also, a handy little tool in VFP9 called TaskPane (Data Explorer tab) allows you to browse through your servers, add/modify connections using OLEDB.

Comment: I've added a little more detail in my original post. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

> So, can I write an application which will run on the glassfish server that will monitor the FoxPro database and write the necessary changes/data to the the SQL server database?

The ideal would be if the FoxPro database could push the changes to your application.  You can do this if FoxPro produces a log of the database changes and your application can read this log.  I'm not enough of a FoxPro expert to say if this method is feasible.

Another process would be for your application to read the FoxPro database periodically.  Say, every 15 minutes.  Then it would be up to your application to figure out what's different and update the SQL Server database.  The SQL Server database would always be behind the FoxPro database by the polling interval.  You would have to determine how often to read the FoxPro database to meet your application's needs.

Comment: I have considered your second suggestion, but I'm not sure if this is an application that I can write and run on the glassfish server.  I'm a complete newbie in this regard. As I said, I don't want to have all of the clients trying to do the same updates to the sql database when they see that the foxpro table has more recent data.

Comment: @kpenrose: It would make more sense to write the extract process as a FoxPro application.  One way would be to have a FoxPro application read the tables and write the rows to a flat file that your Java application can then read and process.

Comment: @kpenrose: Another option would be to upgrade the FoxPro database to a Sybase database.  http://www.sybase.com/visualfoxpro?cmpid=cpc_us_gg_advdb_ads-foxpro&mc=google&mkwid=speNTZD2p_pcrid_12642278482_pmt_p_pkw_foxpro

Comment: Perhaps I'm not being clear enough, but modifying the FoxPro code at all is probably impossible, for a number of reasons.  I could have my client apps read the foxpro data and update the sql tables, but I don't want 10 or more clients trying to perform the same update.  What I think I want to do is write one application, that runs on the glassfish server, which does nothing more than periodically read the foxpro data and update the sql tables when it finds a change.

Comment: This application would not be responsible for replying to client queries or requests, so would not need any http services listening for requests.  Just a simple thread running on the server doing database  updates.  As I said, I'm a complete noob regarding this, so I will need a little more hand-holding than your normal j2ee nerd.