# Understanding my ObservableList

Tags: for-loop, observablecollection

Can someone please help me understand what Java is doing? I've made an ObservableList named data. I add elements to the list, something like this:

```
data.add(new ClientList(LastName, FirstName, Street, City, State, Zip, Telephone, DateOfBirth);
```

So I make a form for adding people to this list, which is held in Java's memory so I can later click a button to add, let's say 5 people to my database. My first question is, would I be correctly describing this as a list of 5 objects, with each object containing 8 values? If not, what would be the proper way, using Java terminology, to describe what has been done here?

Now, given that I have this above ObservableList called data, if I put in the command

```
System.out.println(data.toString())
```

(and assuming I have 5 clients in my list) I would get a list of 5 objects referenced on my screen (albeit only the pointer to their "slot" in memory), correct? Up to this point, I'm really hoping people will either say I'm correct, or tell me my terminology is all wrong and should be [insert correct terminology here]. Or if I'm just way off base, please correct that, too.

Now what I don't understand is, if I write the following code:

```
for (Object o : data) {
    [variable] = data.get(0);
}
```

the integer (0) seems to refer to the object in the list indexed at 0 (which would be all of the values for the first person in the list, right?). NetBeans wants me to make the variable a type "Object" for this, and anything else I put there either gives me a compile error or a runtime error, depending on how I write the statement.

But since I'm iterating over the list, I thought this integer was supposed to point to the first value (in my case, LastName) in the object currently being handled by the for loop. From what I can deduce from how my code runs, I am incorrect, and the previous paragraph is what is going on. How, then, can I read the values for each object in my list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let me answer this, since I *did* figure it out. I may be wrong, but I'd still like to put this here so I have the info later as I continue to learn, and so others might also have it if they run into the same question.

First, I appear to have been correct with the "data.get(0)" being the first *object* in the list, which object was an array of LastName, FirstName, etc. I should not have been using the data.get(int[object]), but rather o.[variable].get(). In this way, the iterator is already getting me one of the many objects, which objects each contain many variables. But the data model defines the getter for each variable, so calling [object].[variable].get() runs the getter, thus returning the correct value and type of the variable within that object.

SO...the correct code for my iterator would be:

```
for (Object o : data) { //"For each object we'll call 'o' in the already defined list named 'data' ..."
    String lastName = o.lastName.get();
        // repeat this pattern for each variable in the object
        // [Type] [variable] = [object].[variable].get();
}
```

with a getter defined in the data model thusly:

```
public SimpleStringProperty lastNameProperty() {
    return lastName;
}
```

(aside: the use of SimpleStringProperty and appending "Property" to the variable "lastName" to make the name of the getter makes it easier to make the CellValueFactory for the columns of a TableView)